RIP Donald Sutherland
Donald Sutherland has just died aged 88, after a seven-decade career in film and television, starring in films ranging from The Dirty Dozen (1967) to Invasion of the Bodysnatchers (1978) to the US adaptation of The Italian Job (2003) to the Hunger Games film series (2012-2015).
RIP: 17 July 1935 – 20 June 2024.



I was genuinely saddened by this. The world has lost a great performer.

The first SF-adjacent role I saw Sutherland in was the video for Kate Bush's song "Cloudbusting."

Last survivor of The Dirty Dozen, I am pretty sure and he was one of the youngest -- probably one of the extras could be still around.
I am wrong: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuart_Cooper
